# Positioning and size of a graphic

Tags: pgfplots

I want to present a graph associated with another image: when I do it with a `\scope` environment, I cannot correctly position the graph or change its size
I also have a problem to add a single value on the y-axis (the value 1).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-spectra}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% Preamble: 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  function sinc2(\x) {
    if  abs(\x) < .001 then { % (|x| < .001) ~ (x = 0)
      return 1;
    } else {
      return (sin(\x r)/\x)*(sin(\x r)/\x);
    };
  };
}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \fill (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
        \fill [white] (-0.05,-2) rectangle (0.05,2);
\end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \begin{axis}[yscale=2]%
    [grid=both,
     minor tick num=1,
     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
     major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     axis lines=middle,
        xtick={-9.42477796, -6.28318, -3.14159, 3.14159, 6.28318, 9.42477796
    },
        xticklabels={$-3\pi$, $-2\pi$,  $-\pi$,$\pi$,  $2\pi$, $3\pi$}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=200,smooth,red] {sinc2(x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With change of rectangle vertical coordinates:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  function sinc2(\x) {
    if  abs(\x) < .001 then { % (|x| < .001) ~ (x = 0)
      return 1;
    } else {
      return (sin(\x r)/\x)*(sin(\x r)/\x);
    };
  };
}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}               
    \fill (-3,0) rectangle (3,6); % <---
    \fill[white] (-0.05,1) rectangle (0.05,5); % <---

\begin{axis}[xshift=4cm,          % <---
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=1,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    xtick={-3*pi, -2*pi, -pi, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi},
    xticklabels={$-3\pi$, $-2\pi$, $-\pi$,$\pi$, $2\pi$, $3\pi$}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=200,red] {sinc2(x))};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-spectra}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% Preamble: 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
    function sinc2(\x) {
        if  abs(\x) < .001 then { % (|x| < .001) ~ (x = 0)
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (sin(\x r)/\x)*(sin(\x r)/\x);
        };
    };
}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    %--------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \fill (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
            \fill [white] (-0.05,-2) rectangle (0.05,2);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm,yshift=-3cm]
            \begin{axis}%[yscale=2]%
                [grid=both,
                minor tick num=1,
                grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
                major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
                axis lines=middle,
                xtick={-9.42477796, -6.28318, -3.14159, 3.14159, 6.28318, 9.42477796
                },
                xticklabels={$-3\pi$, $-2\pi$,  $-\pi$,$\pi$,  $2\pi$, $3\pi$}
                ]
                \addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=200,smooth,red] {sinc2(x))};
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You have this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a scope for this, but `anchor` and `at`. You do not write how you want them placed, so I am guessing.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\fill[white] (-0.05,-2) rectangle (0.05,2);
\begin{axis}[ 
anchor=left of origin, at={(4cm,-3cm)},
grid=both,
minor tick num=1,
grid style={gray!20},
axis lines=middle,
xtick={-3*pi, -2*pi, -pi, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi},
xticklabels={$-3\pi$, $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, $2\pi$, $3\pi$},
trig format plots=rad,
]
\addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi, samples=100, smooth, red] {abs(x)>0.001?(sin(x)/x)^2:1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Black rectangle and a graph]

If you want you your axis to be the same height as the rectangle, you can use the options:

```
scale only axis=true, height=6cm,
```